# Cannot connect to MySQL database which contains Chinese character

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to read data from MySQL databases in to a C# program.However,I found that  exception **MySql.Data.MySqlClientException(0x80004005)** would be thrown every time I try to connect to a database whose name contains Chinese character.

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;password=****;databasename='漢語數據庫'"
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```

The *error message* is as follows,for example:

**Authentication to... failed with message:Unknown database '????'.** It appears that '?' has replaced all the Chinese characters.

I'm wondering if I should set a decoder such as *UTF8* or *GB2312*,but I don't know how to do it.

BTW,I can neither add a connection to MySQL dbs which contain Chinese characters in **Visual Studio 2013**,a similar error message would be thrown as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its unicode encoding problem. use 
"Server=localhost;Database=root;Uid=test;Pwd=test;Charset=utf8;"

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work.Exception **MySql.Data.MySqlClientException(0x80004005) ** would still be thrown.